# Not able to remove the apostrophe

Tags: c#, asp.net

This piece of code works properly if there is any value without the apostrophe. But if the ddList.SelectedValue is, say, Women's day, it shows "Incorrect syntax near 's'. Unclosed quotation mark after the character string ''."
I tried the albumName.Replace but no luck so far.

```
protected void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string albumName = ddList.SelectedValue.ToString();
    albumName.Replace("'", "''");

    conn.Open();
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("select ID from Album where AlbumName = '" + albumName + "'", conn);

    SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        AlbmID = Int32.Parse((reader["ID"].ToString())); 

    }
    reader.Close();

    if (fileuploadimages.HasFile == false)
    { ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "key", "<script>alert('No File Uploaded.')</script>", false); }
    else
    {
        //Get Filename from fileupload control
        string filename = Path.GetFileName(fileuploadimages.PostedFile.FileName);
        //Save images into SlideImages folder
        fileuploadimages.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("Pictures/" + filename));
        //Open the database connection

        //Query to insert images name and Description into database
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into Images(ImagePath,Album_ID,ImageDesc) values(@ImagePath,@Album_ID,@ImageDesc)", conn);
        //Passing parameters to query
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ImagePath", filename);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Album_ID", AlbmID);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ImageDesc", txtDescription.Text);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        //Close dbconnection
        conn.Close();
        txtDescription.Text = "";
        BindDataList();
    }
}
```

Comment: You have a SQL injection vulnerability.  You need to use parameters.

Comment: I know that. Is that the reason of this problem?

Comment: It looks like you already know how to use parameters (your second query).  Why don't you (your first query)?  That's *exactly* how you would fix this.  Currently your first query is ***executing user input as code*** which is basically allowing any user to execute any code they want in your database.

Comment: @David Let me try that.

Comment: @user3229034 Yes, that will fix this, since setting a parameter value to your `albumName` will ensure that the string is escaped. I sincerely hope that this code is not in your code-behind for a page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("select ID from Album where AlbumName = @name", conn);
command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@name", albumName));
.
.
.
```

In addition, you should wrap the connection,command, and reader objects in a `using() {}` construct to dispose of the resources in a timely fashion.

Use parameters like this whenever dynamic things are being put into a SQL string to avoid errors like this, as well as SQL injection attacks and other vulnerabilities.

In addition, you can rapidly replace parameters for executing multiple queries without having the rebuild the string.

Answer (score 1):

```
.Replace("'",@"\'")
```

This will escape your single quote/apostrophe